# Button Point Optimisation

Tags: probability, optimization

this is a question I received from a friend.

“A gentleman pressed a button 120 times. Every 30 times pressed, he gets 10 points. Every 20 times pressed, he gets 5 points. Every 10 times, he gets 3 points.”

a. What is the most points he can earn?

b. There is a 10% chance that a push does not give any point. For example, if this applies, no matter how many time he pushes this time, it still gives 0. What is the most points he can earn in this case?

That probability only applies to question B. Answers, and ways, will be appreciated.

Thank you.